# Methods of initializing weights in Convolutional Neural Networks - Python/TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I initially set my weights as follows:

```
def new_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.05))
```

But I realized that I had weights -0 as in the following figure:

[image: Figure 1]

Then I decided to define it that way, and for me the weights are more acceptable:

```
def new_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape))
```

[image: Figure 2]

I want to know what the implication of using tf.truncated_normal is and what does the -zeros mean? And if you have any problems initializing them like this.

And between the two I introduced, what would be the best method of initializing weights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tf.truncated_normal** outputs random values from a truncated normal distribution. Therefore, have good convergence properties in DNN. Following graphs are the validation loss (left) and validation accuracy (right) of a CNN on MNIST dataset. Used weight initializations are as follows,

1. Zero: When all weights are set to 0
2. Random: When weights are set completely randomly
3. Random between -1 to +1: Random weights on the scale of -1 to +1
4. Xavier-Glorot Initialization

[image]

As you can see, random weights on the scale of -1 to +1 have shown good results. Therefore, it is the most commonly used weight initialization method in DNN.

References,
https://medium.com/@amarbudhiraja/towards-weight-initialization-in-deep-neural-networks-908d3d9f1e02

Comment: Okay, but what does the -zeros mean? Does it mean they tend to -1?

Comment: What u mean by -zeros ?

Comment: -0.064785, etc. In tf.truncated_normal

Comment: That's because of its a truncated normal distribution. Truncated means its only outputs values whose magnitude is within 2 standard deviations from the mean=0. This means values are between 0.1 and -0,1

Comment: I see! What does stddev  = 0.05 mean?

Comment: That means the standard deviation of the truncated normal distribution is 0.05.